# Dereferencing the first return value in go

Tags: pointers, go, dereference

I have  Go function, and I want to dereference the first value to store in a pointer.

E.g.:

```
func foo() (int64, error) {...}
var A *int64
var err error
A, err = &foo()
```

Is this possible, or do I have to copy the (in my case very large) return value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the pointer of return value from function call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744965/how-to-get-the-pointer-of-return-value-from-function-call) Also related: [How can I store reference to the result of an operation in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197248/how-can-i-store-reference-to-the-result-of-an-operation-in-go)

Comment: I had assumed that I could do it a for a single-value function call, so I didn't even see that; I guess ultimately this means the question is moot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that. The address operator `&` cannot be applied on function calls.

[Spec: Address operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)

> For an operand `x` of type `T`, the address operation `&x` generates a pointer of type `*T` to `x`. The operand must be *addressable*, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the addressability requirement, `x` may also be a (possibly parenthesized) [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals). If the evaluation of `x` would cause a [run-time panic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics), then the evaluation of `&x` does too.

What you should do is change your function to return a pointer in the first place, if it does matter.