# Error addressing the returned slice of a function

Tags: string, go, call, slice

In the next code the first `Println` fails on build with error `slice of unaddressable value`. The rest of the lines are just fine.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func getSlice() [0]int {
   return [...]int{}
}

func getString() string {
   return "hola"
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getSlice()[:]) // Error: slice of unaddressable value

    var a = getSlice()
    fmt.Println(a[:])

    fmt.Println(getString()[:])

    var b = getString()
    fmt.Println(b[:])
}
```

[Try this code](https://play.golang.org/p/qTE8U_PyPqc)

If the first `Println` is commented it works. 
[Try it out](https://play.golang.org/p/81OqZFtxla1)

Why is that? What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're missing is that when slicing an *array*, the operand must be addressable (`[0]int` is an array, not a slice). And return values of function calls are not addressable. For details see [How can I store reference to the result of an operation in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197248/how-can-i-store-reference-to-the-result-of-an-operation-in-go/34197367#34197367); and ["cannot take the address of" and "cannot call pointer method on"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543374/cannot-take-the-address-of-and-cannot-call-pointer-method-on/44543748#44543748).

[Spec: Slice expressions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)

> If the sliced operand is an array, it must be [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) and the result of the slice operation is a slice with the same element type as the array.

In this expression:

```
getSlice()[:]
```

`getSlice()` returns an *array*, and since it's the result of a function call, it's not addressable. Therefore you cannot slice it.

In this expression:

```
getString()[:]
```

`getString()` returns a `string` value, so it can be sliced even if the value is not addressable. This is allowed, because the result of the slice expression will be another `string`, and `string` values in Go are immutable.

Also, variables are [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), so this will always work:

```
var a = getSlice()
fmt.Println(a[:])
```

Comment: I still did not understand why `getString()[:]` would work.

Comment: @naneri Because the operand in the slicing expression only needs to be addressable if it's an array, but not if it's a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

`getSlice()` is not returning a slice it's returning an array, which is not addressable. You could return a pointer to the array:

```
func getSlice() *[0]int {
   return &[...]int{}
}
```

or leave `getSlice()` as is and place the result in a temporary variable:

```
t := getSlice()
fmt.Println(t[:])
```