# Golang generic not working when used as map element

Tags: go, pointers

I created a MapKeys generic and List generic, but when using List generic with normal map[string]List[int], I can't call the generic's method, what I am wrong? any ideas will be very appreciated!

generic code like this :

```
package main

import "fmt"

func MapKeys[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V) []K {
    r := make([]K, 0, len(m))
    for k := range m {
        r = append(r, k)
    }
    return r
}

type List[T any] struct {
    head, tail *element[T]
}

type element[T any] struct {
    next *element[T]
    val  T
}

func (lst *List[T]) Push(v T) {
    if lst.tail == nil {
        lst.head = &element[T]{val: v}
        lst.tail = lst.head
    } else {
        lst.tail.next = &element[T]{val: v}
        lst.tail = lst.tail.next
    }
}

func (lst *List[T]) GetAll() []T {
    var elems []T
    for e := lst.head; e != nil; e = e.next {
        elems = append(elems, e.val)
    }
    return elems
}

func main() {
    var m = map[int]string{1: "2", 2: "4", 4: "8"}

    fmt.Println("keys m:", MapKeys(m))

    _ = MapKeys[int, string](m)

    var yx = make(map[string]List[int])
    yx["one"] = List[int]{}
    yx["one"].Push(10)

    lst := List[int]{}
    lst.Push(10)
    lst.Push(13)
    lst.Push(23)
    fmt.Println("list:", lst.GetAll())
}
```

call this line :

```
yx["one"].Push(10)
```

### got the error message :

./prog.go:49:12: cannot call pointer method Push on List[int]

you can play the code [here](https://go.dev/play/p/stEkN7itAlv?v=goprev)

Comment: Note that this is unrelated to generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.Push()` has pointer receiver, but you store non-pointers in the map, and indexing maps is not [addressable](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators). For details see [Cannot take the address of map element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321933/cannot-take-the-address-of-map-element/57322003#57322003).

Store pointers in the map, and then you can call methods with pointer receivers on map index results:

```
var yx = make(map[string]*List[int])
yx["one"] = &List[int]{}
yx["one"].Push(10)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/zwL9J4PdL-n).

Note: you can call methods with pointer receiver on non-pointer values if the value is addressable, such as a variable:

```
lst := List[int]{}
lst.Push(10)
```

The above `lst.Push(10)` is a shorthand for `(&lst).Push(10)`. For details see [Pointer methods on non pointer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956290/pointer-methods-on-non-pointer-types/46956348#46956348).