# assignment of function result

Tags: go

Coming from C#, this puzzles me.
In Go, if I have

```
type Employee struct {
   ID     int
   Salary int
}
```

then I can do

```
var tom Employee
tom.Salary = 100
```

so far so good. Then if I have a function

```
func employeeByID(id int) Employee {
   // do something and return an employee
}
```

Then why does this not compile?

```
employeeByID(10).Salary = 100
```

Moreover, this seems to compile fine:

```
andrew := employeeByID(10)
andrew.Salary = 100
```

Comment: What do you expect `employeeByID(10).Salary = 100` to do? It would make sense if the function returned `*Employee` instead.

Comment: For the same reason you can't do `5 = 10`. Why would you want to assign a value to something that itself is not stored anywhere?

Comment: You can't do it even in C#

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't compile because that assignment is not valid.

[Spec: Assignments:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments)

> Each left-hand side operand must be [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), a map index expression, or (for = assignments only) the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier).

The return values of function calls are not addressable. For details, see [How to get the pointer of return value from function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744965/how-to-get-the-pointer-of-return-value-from-function-call/30751102#30751102) and [How can I store reference to the result of an operation in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197248/how-can-i-store-reference-to-the-result-of-an-operation-in-go/34197367#34197367)

Think about it: you call a function, it returns a value (which you don't store), what good would come from changing it if you don't store the result? It would be discarded, and so the assignment would also be useless.

If you store the result in a variable like in your second example, you can change its fields because variables are addressable.