# dereferencing string literal in Go

Tags: go, dereference, string-literals

I am playing with Go and facing the following question:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var arr [2]*string
    var s1 string = "hello"
    arr[0] = &s1
    arr[1] = &"world"   // can't compile
    fmt.Println(arr[0], arr[1])
    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

After compiling the above code I got the next error:

```
prog.go:10: cannot take the address of "world"
```

What is the reason I cannot obtain the address of the string literal?
And if it is possible how can I do that?

Note: I obtained the address of `s1`. Should I always introduce variables for literals to get back their addresses?

Comment: You cannot because literals are not addressable by the language spec.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, literals are hard-coded into the executable binary and therefore can not be referenced.

Comment: Related: [How do I do a literal *int64 in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go) Same applies here just with `string` instead of `int64`.