# Would you ever have to lock const with a mutex lock?

Tags: go, concurrency, locking, constants, mutex

I am programming in go and using mutex lock to lock certain variables so they cannot be overwritten while being read.

This got me thinking. Since you can read a variable multiple times. Is there a scenario where you ever have to lock a constant variable?

Comment: Can you change a constant? No. If you can't, may there be a case when it is being written and read at the same time?

Comment: @icza This is why I was wondering it. Would there be a certain way it has a point of using it with a constant. Thank you for reacting and reading so fast!

Comment: "constant variable" is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is simple: if multiple goroutines access a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) concurrently, and at least one of the accesses is a write, then synchronization is required.

If we talk about [constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants), then there is no variable, and you cannot take the address of a constant (for details, see [Find address of constant in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146286/find-address-of-constant-in-go/35146856#35146856)), so it is not possible to modify constant values.

You do not need any synchronization to access constants from multiple goroutines.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about constants there is no need to use sync routines to access them (as @icza suggests).

But if you consider const as variable whose value cannot be changed once it has been assigned a value, then you should be careful because of golang memory model and [happens before](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_2) relationship.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. A constant is a constant, not a variable, and its value is defined at compile time, not at run time. "if you consider const as variable" then you don't know what a constant is.

Comment: There is a little misunderstanding caused by OPs "constant variable" term. That's why I added this "if you consider..." part. Meaning, that if you use variable as a constant then you can face some pitfalls.