# Go struct literals, why is this one addressable?

Tags: pointers, go, struct, language-lawyer, composite-literals

I am reading the book "The Go Programming Language". It is very good for us (rather) experienced programmers and explains the differences between the intersection of other languages -- but I've found a case which I do not understand fully.

I know C++ sufficiently good, and I understand that Go calls (what in C++ would be called) rvalues/xvalues "non-addressable". Only *"variables"* [GOPL's words] are addressable.

**OK, fair enough; it makes sense.**

And therefore, for instance, this is illegal (according to page 159 in the first printing)

```
Point{1, 2}.ScaleBy(2) // compile error: can't take address of Point literal
```

because `(*Point).ScaleBy` takes a `*Point` as a receiver argument, and a `Point` literal is non-addressable.

(If you haven't read the book, `Point` is a struct with the fields `X, Y float64`.

**However**, on page 162, we have

```
type ColoredPoint struct {
    *Point
    Color color.RGBA
}

p := ColoredPoint(&Point{1, 1}, red)
// ...more code ...
```

which apparently is valid and will compile.

**Question:**

Why is the `Point` literal in the second case addressable?

Is it a special case for convenience, or am I missing something in the big picture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&T{}` notation is explained in Section 4.4.1, Struct Literals, on page 103:

> Because structs are so commonly dealt with through pointers, it’s possible to use this shorthand notation to create and initialize a struct variable and obtain its address:
>
> ```
> pp := &Point{1, 2}
> ```
>
> It is exactly equivalent to
>
> ```
> pp := new(Point)
> *pp = Point{1, 2}
> ```
>
> but `&Point{1, 2}` can be used directly within an expression, such as a function call.

Glad you're otherwise enjoying the book.

Comment: I really do enjoy it! Though I am reading it (in more or less in a hurry) because I will most likely land a job writing Go code full-time very soon. Must have missed this part. I think this is up there with K&D.... I mean K&R. ;-) Thanks again!

Comment: Is it rather equivalent to `var pp *Point; *pp = Point{1, 2}` not `pp := new(Point)`? Newly created zero-valued `Point` object is overwritten by `Point{1, 2}`, isn't it? (Yes, yes, I dare to ask to author of the Go book :-) )

Answer (score 2):

It's a special case for convenience.  The spec mentions the exception [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators).

> As an exception to the addressability requirement, x may also be a (possibly parenthesized) composite literal.

Comment: Thank you, this is obviously the direct answer to my question. I will mark it as such soon.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a little more detail to Mellow Marmot's answer:

[Spec: Variables:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables)

> Calling the built-in function [`new`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation) or taking the address of a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) allocates storage for a variable at run time. Such an anonymous variable is referred to via a (possibly implicit) [pointer indirection](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators).

`Point{1, 1}` is a composite literal, taking its address will create an anonymous variable under the hood, and the result of the expression will be the address of this anonymous variable.

So as you can see technically it's a *variable* that is addressed, so it does not violate this:

> Only *"variables"* [GOPL's words] are addressable.

Also check out this answer to see what other "goodies" or tricks you can do: [How do I do a literal *int64 in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go/30716481#30716481)

Comment: Thank you for adding to the accepted answer! Very useful info.