# Unmarshal JSON with "valid" zero values

Tags: json, pointers, go, unmarshalling

I have some JSON that I am unmarshalling into various structs so that I can then process the data, seemingly this is turning into the hardest part of the project!!!

The format of this JSON is that if the field is missing then it is essentially nil.  This is following on from [Default struct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970422/default-struct-values) but thought it deserved it's own question on SO.

A zero therefore is a valid value and I need to be able to discern this in my Go code.  Is there a way to get Go to unmarshal into this struct with pointers at all?

In the example [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/B3-sos2FaH) you can see what I mean, it "appears" to work but when I come to print out one of the pointer values it always prints the pointer address and not the actual value.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "log"
import "encoding/json"

const inputMissing = `
["AAAAAA", {"testCode" : "Sss"}, 123456]
`

const inputZero = `
["AAAAAA", {"testCode" : "Sss", "missingInt" : 0, "defaultInt" : 0,"missingString" : "", "defaultString" : ""}, 123456]
`

type RawMessage struct {
    AlwaysString  string
    ClientData    ClientData
    ReceptionTime int
}

type ClientData struct {
    TestCode   string
    MissingInt *int
    DefaultInt int

    MissingString *string
    DefaultString string
}

func main() {

    var n RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputMissing), &n); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", n)

    var o RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputZero), &o); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", o)

    fmt.Printf("Should print the value of the int, not pointer... %i", o.ClientData.MissingInt)
}

func (n *RawMessage) UnmarshalJSON(buf []byte) error {
    tmp := []interface{}{&n.AlwaysString, &n.ClientData, &n.ReceptionTime}
    wantLen := len(tmp)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(buf, &tmp); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if g, e := len(tmp), wantLen; g != e {
        return fmt.Errorf("wrong number of fields in RawMessage: %d != %d", g, e)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. If you need the value, why won't you just check the pointer against `nil` and then dereference it?

Comment: I am not sure the unmarshal is setting the value correctly.  Whatever I do I cannot get the 0 (or any other value) able to be read from `MissingInt` or `MissingString`

Comment: Maybe a better example is https://play.golang.org/p/RWKCFtlhMk, I can't get to print out/read the 555 or test

Comment: Why just not this? https://play.golang.org/p/aQ7Jjzgfja

Comment: Yes sorry, I feel really stupid now to not have checked that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct. Test the pointer against nil and dereference the pointer if you want the value:

```
fmt.Printf("Should print the value of the int, not pointer... %d", *o.ClientData.MissingInt)
```

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I was missing that!  I feel like an idiot now!

Comment: You should not. There is no such thing as a stupid question.

Comment: Thanks!  When using pointers there instead of values in the struct do I have to be careful with memory leaks at all or will GC still kick in for the whole struct when I am done with the object?

Comment: GC will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion arises from the default formatting of the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package, which prints the hex value in case of pointer fields, and not the pointed value.

If you're using the `%#v` verb for printing, you may implement the [`fmt.GoStringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#GoStringer) interface on your struct to override this "behavior":

```
func (c ClientData) GoString() string {
    mi := "<missing>"
    if c.MissingInt != nil {
        mi = strconv.Itoa(*c.MissingInt)
    }
    ms := "<missing>"
    if c.MissingString != nil {
        ms = *c.MissingString
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("{TestCode: %s, MissingInt: %s, DefaultInt: %d, MissingString: %s, DefaultString: %s}",
        c.TestCode, mi, c.DefaultInt, ms, c.DefaultString)
}
```

And changing the last printing line to:

```
fmt.Printf("Should print the value of the int, not pointer... %d",
    *o.ClientData.MissingInt)
```

Your output becomes more readable (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RdEXV-DcTm)):

```
main.RawMessage{AlwaysString:"AAAAAA", ClientData:{TestCode: Sss, MissingInt: <missing>, DefaultInt: 0, MissingString: <missing>, DefaultString: }, ReceptionTime:123456}
main.RawMessage{AlwaysString:"AAAAAA", ClientData:{TestCode: Sss, MissingInt: 0, DefaultInt: 0, MissingString: , DefaultString: }, ReceptionTime:123456}
Should print the value of the int, not pointer... 0
```

As you can see from the output above, the `MissingXX` fields have the static value `<missing>` displayed.

**Note:** If you were to use the `%v` verb, you'd have to implement the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface, which is basically the same, just the method name is not `GoString()` but simply `String()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this.  That was very useful.