# Determine if value was provided in json string while unmarshal

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

When unmarshalling json into a struct, I'd like to look at the struct (or any other meta data vehicle) to know the whether a json value was provided in the json input or if a json value was omitted from the json input.  Consider this code as an example:

```
package main
import (
  "encoding/json"
  "log"
)

type Person struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Grades []Grade `json:"grades"`
}

type Grade struct {
  Year int `json:"year"`
  Grade int `json:"grade"`
}

func main() {
  jsonString := `{"name":"john","grades":[{"year":1998,"grade":0},{"year":1999}]}`

  person := Person{}
  _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString),&person)

  log.Println(person)
}
```

The log prints `{john [{1998 0} {1999 0}]}`.  What is idiomatic way in Go to know that the zero of `1998 0` was explicitly declared in the JSON string while the zero of `1999 0` was the default zero when initializing the `struct Grade`?

The reason I want to know this difference is because I want to use this struct to create an SQL statement that updates the table field `t_grade.grade = ?` if and only if the zero was explicitly provided by the json string.  Also note that `t_grade.grade` in the database is not-nullable.

I am currently using a hack where my grade struct looks like this:

```
type Grade struct {
  Year *int `json:"year"`
  Grade *int `json:"grade"`
}
```

So if the JSON string does not provide a value, then the grade field will be null.  Otherwise, the grade field will hold a pointer to a value.

But I'm sure there's a better and idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: If the zero value is a valid / useful value, use a pointer to the type. `nil` pointer value will denote the missing case, and a non-`nil` value pointing to the zero value will denote the "present" zero value. Using a non-pointer type, you can't differentiate a missing value from a present zero value (see [Default struct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970422/default-struct-values/40970490#40970490)).

Comment: ok thanks, that's the hack i mentioned in my question, was really hoping to avoid it

Comment: There is no easier way, see my edited comment. You could create your own `NullString` type and implement custom marshaling / unmarshaling on it, but that wouldn't be easier to read or use imo.