# Json unmarshal struct to map is ignoring zero values of struct

Tags: go

I am trying to convert a struct to map using following method

```
func ConvertStructToMap(in interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    fmt.Println(in)
    var inInterface map[string]interface{}
    inrec, _ := json.Marshal(in)
    json.Unmarshal(inrec, &inInterface)
    return inInterface

}
```

The problem is when I am trying to convert a struct

```
type Data struct{
 Thing string `json:"thing,omitempty"`
 Age uint8 `json:"age,omitempty"`

}
```

With this data

```
c:=Data{
  Thing :"i",
  Age:0,
}
```

it just gives me the following output `map[things:i]` instead it should give the output
`map[things:i,age:0]`

And when I don't supply age

like below

```
 c:=Data{
      Thing :"i",
      
    }
```

Then it should give this output `map[things:i]` .I am running an update query and the user may or may not supply the fields ,any way to solve it .I have looked over the internet but couldn't get my head on place

Edit -
I am sending json from frontend which gets converted to struct with [go fiber Body parser](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/ctx#body)

```
if err := c.BodyParser(&payload); err != nil {
        
    }
```

Now  If I send following  payload from frontend

```
{
  thing:"ii"
}
```

the bodyParser converts it into

```
Data{
          Thing :"ii",
          Age :0
          
        }
```

that's why I have used `omitempty` such that bodyParser can ignore the field which are not present

Comment: It is ignoring fields with zero value because _you asked_ it with the `,omitempty` option. If you want all fields, remove the `,omitempty` options from the tags.

Comment: Actually I am sending a json from frontend which gets converted to struct  by `ctx.BodyParser() of gofiber `then I am converting the struct to map ,if i remove omitempty ,Bodyparser just gives me whole struct with empty fields :(

Comment: You can directly convert the request body to map using `ctx.BodyParser()`

    `var payload map[string]interface{}

    if err := c.BodyParser(&payload); err != nil {
            
        }`. As BodyParser takes interface as argument

Comment: There is no difference between "set to zero" or "left to zero" fields, see [Default struct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970422/default-struct-values/40970490#40970490). `Data{Thing: "i", Age: 0}` is equivalent to `Data{Thing: "i"}`. Use pointers if you need this.

Answer (score 0):

omitempty ignore when convert from struct to json

```
type Response struct {
 Age int `json:"age,omitempty"`
 Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

resp:=Response {
  Name: "john",
}

 data,_:=json.Marshal(&resp)
fmt.Println(string(data)) => {"name": "john"}
```

In you case, you convert from json to struct, if attribute not present, it will be fill with default value of data type, in this case is 0 with uint8