# initialize string pointer in struct

Tags: pointers, go, struct

Go Newbie question: I am trying to init the following struct, with a default value. I know that it works if "Uri" is a string and not pointer to a string (*string). But i need this pointer for comparing two  instances of the struct, where Uri would be nil if not set, e.g. when i demarshal content from a json file. But how can I initialize such a struct  properly as a "static default"?

```
type Config struct {
  Uri       *string
}

func init() {
  var config = Config{ Uri: "my:default" }
}
```

The code above fails with

```
cannot use "string" (type string) as type *string in field value
```

Comment: You can use package [pointer](https://github.com/xorcare/pointer), for example: var _ *string = pointer.String("my:default")

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It's not possible to get the address (to point) of a constant value, which is why your initialization fails. If you define a variable and pass its address, your example will work.

```
type Config struct {
  Uri       *string
}

func init() {
  v := "my:default"
  var config = Config{ Uri: &v }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a one liner so that the `v := "my:default"` wouldn't be needed?

Comment: The accepted answer here also applies to strings. There are several ways to do it as a one-liner, but they are ugly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go/30716481

Comment: I was also looking for a one-liner, but unfortunately, this looks better and easy to read.

Comment: @Zamicol in my previous and current company, we simply create helper functions (StrPtr(val string), Int64Ptr(val int64), etc). I think it's a common enough situation to make it useful.

Comment: A better way without new variable assignment:

`func String(v string) *string { return &v }`

func init(){
  var config = Config{
      Uri: String("my:default") 
  }
}

Comment: The closest I could come up with is `(func(s string) *string { return &s })("my:default")`