# Cannot convert (untyped string constant) to *string

Tags: string, go

```
persistentvolumeclaim := &apiv1.PersistentVolumeClaim{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: "mysql-pv-claim",
        },
        Spec: apiv1.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec{
            StorageClassName: "manual",
            },
    }
```

`StorageClassName` parameter takes pointer to string, but compiler gives error when i'm passing string `"manual"` into it.

Answer (score 23):

[You cannot get the address of a string constant/literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594789/initialize-string-pointer-in-struct), but if you have a `string` local variable (set to the value you want) you can then pass the address of that local:

Declare a `string` local first and assign the constant string literal to it, then pass the address of that local as the parameter argument with the `&` operator:

```
persistentvolumeclaim := &apiv1.PersistentVolumeClaim {

        manualStr := "manual"

        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta {
            Name: "mysql-pv-claim",
        },
        Spec: apiv1.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec {
            StorageClassName: &manualStr,
        },
    }
```

Comment: now showing error in this line :-         manualStr := "manual"

Comment: @manjeet My mistake, it's been a while since I last used Go. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [utils.StringPtr](https://godoc.org/github.com/kubernetes/utils/pointer#StringPtr):

```
persistentvolumeclaim := &apiv1.PersistentVolumeClaim{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: "mysql-pv-claim",
        },
        Spec: apiv1.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec{
            StorageClassName: utils.StringPtr("manual"),
            },
    }
```

Comment: Now it's showing :- undeclared name: utils.
What package i have to import for this.
it shows error when i import this package: "github.com/kubernetes/utils/pointer"

Comment: Don't import an entire package to get a one line function. You can write that function in your code if you need to do this more than a couple times.