# How to use map[string]*string

Tags: string, dictionary, pointers, go, sarama

I'm trying to use sarama (Admin mode) to create a topic.
Without the ConfigEntries works fine. But I need to define some configs.

I set up the topic config (Here is happening the error):

```
    tConfigs := map[string]*string{
        "cleanup.policy":      "delete",
        "delete.retention.ms": "36000000",
    }
```

But then I get an error:

```
./main.go:99:28: cannot use "delete" (type string) as type *string in map value
./main.go:100:28: cannot use "36000000" (type string) as type *string in map value
```

I'm trying to use the admin mode like this:

```
err = admin.CreateTopic(t.Name, &sarama.TopicDetail{
    NumPartitions:     1,
    ReplicationFactor: 3,
    ConfigEntries:     tConfigs,
}, false)
```

Here is the line from the sarama module that defines CreateTopic()
https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/admin.go#L18

Basically, I didn't understand how the map of pointers strings works :)

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You can't use a string as a pointer to string. What part is unclear?

Comment: I'm new to golang :)

I didn't get yet how pointer string works.

I understand that a pointer is pointing directly to the value in memory of a variable.

But I don't understant what is a map of pointers strings. 

Should I create a var test string

Then point to this var like *test?

Comment: Okay. I suggest starting with [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/). Specifically [the section on pointers](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To initialize a map having `string` pointer value type with a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), you have to use `string` pointer values. A `string` literal is not a pointer, it's just a `string` value.

An easy way to get a pointer to a `string` value is to take the address of a variable of `string` type, e.g.:

```
s1 := "delete"
s2 := "36000000"

tConfigs := map[string]*string{
    "cleanup.policy":      &s1,
    "delete.retention.ms": &s2,
}
```

To make it convenient when used many times, create a helper function:

```
func strptr(s string) *string { return &s }
```

And using it:

```
tConfigs := map[string]*string{
    "cleanup.policy":      strptr("delete"),
    "delete.retention.ms": strptr("36000000"),
}
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bf4z8IivQ_K).

See background and other options here: [How do I do a literal *int64 in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go/30716481#30716481)