# Converting bool to *bool in go

Tags: go

With the following code:

```
var example *bool
example = true
log.Print(example)
```

I have the following error `cannot convert true (untyped bool constant) to *bool`

I manage to solve it declaring a new variable `truevalue`:

```
var example *bool
truevalue := true
example = &truevalue
log.Print(example)
```

But I imagine there is a better way to do it, without declaring any new variables.

Comment: Well, that pointer has to point _somewhere_.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no better way.

Comment: There are several (cumbersome) ways to do this. They're all cataloged [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go). Your approach is the one I usually take, though.

Comment: @Flimzy the solutions in the example are cumbersome because the need is different, they're trying to assign to a pointer field of a struct literal.

Comment: @Adrian: Which is another way of saying "without declaring new variables", no?

Comment: @Flimzy I don't think so, no. My understanding of the question is that `example` is the only variable they want to declare, and they want to avoid declaring a new variable (`truevalue` in the post), which they can do just using `new()` to initialize the pointer.

Comment: @Adrian: But then you have a zero value. The OP seems to want to set an explicit value.

Comment: @Flimzy you have a pointer to a zero value, which you can then easily set to an explicit value without needing to create an extra variable, thereby solving the stated problem.

Comment: See [Value and Pointer Conversions](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws#hdr-Value_and_Pointer_Conversion_Utilities) in the AWS SDK for one way to handle this problem.  More often than not, people asking this question are grappling with the AWS SDK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A pointer has to point to something, which means you have to either assign it to the address of another variable (as in your second example), or initialize it with `new()` and then assign by dereference. Personally I'd recommend the former, as `new` is not widely used in Go. But, for demonstration:

```
example := new(bool)
*example = true
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0VO5jNPMutQ