# Go function to return pointer of any type?

Tags: go, pointers

Using Go 1.16

Currently no plan to use Go 1.18

---

We have a scenario of using below struct:

```
type X struct {
    M1 *int64
    M2 *string
    M3 *[]string
}
```

---

For below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type X struct {
    M1 *int64
    M2 *string
    M3 *[]string
}

func main() {

    slice := []string{"abc", "def"}

    getIntPointer := func(i int64) *int64 {

        return &i
    }

    getStringPointer := func(s string) *string {
        return &s
    }

    getStringSlicePointer := func(slice []string) *[]string {
        return &slice
    }

    value := X{
        M1: getIntPointer(time.Now().Unix()),
        M2: getStringPointer("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"),
        M3: getStringSlicePointer(slice),
    }
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

---

This function should expect input argument of any type (not just the above three types). Goal is to initialize `value`.

Can a single function return a pointer of any type?

Comment: @icza No, we have no permission to use Go 1.18 compiler as of now, in our team

Answer (score 7):

Type of the `M1`, `M2` and `M3` fields are different, so without generics (Go 1.18) you can't have a function that have multiple return types, assignable to these different fields.

Before showing what's possible with older versions of Go (pre 1.18), let me tell you that I would not use them in production. They are inconvenient and slow (due to reflection). I would write helpers for different types and use those, or use a library that already has them, e.g. [`github.com/icza/gox`](https://github.com/icza/gox) (package [`gox`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icza/gox/gox)) (disclosure: I'm the author).

And if Go 1.18 is allowed, I would use the generic solution shown at the end.

#### `set()` using reflection

What you can do is write a helper that gets the address of a field and the value you want to set for it (more precisely a pointer to it), and using reflection this is doable.

This is how this helper could look like:

```
func set(p, v interface{}) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    rp := reflect.New(rv.Type())
    rp.Elem().Set(rv)
    reflect.ValueOf(p).Elem().Set(rp)
}
```

Using it:

```
slice := []string{"abc", "def"}

var value X
set(&value.M1, time.Now().Unix())
set(&value.M2, "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
set(&value.M3, slice)

fmt.Println(*value.M1, *value.M2, *value.M3)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/zhbxH52JNus)):

```
1257894000 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 [abc def]
```

#### `ptr()` using reflection and type assertion

Another, similarly inconvenient solution would be to write a single helper that returns a pointer to its argument using reflection:

```
func ptr(v interface{}) interface{} {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    rp := reflect.New(rv.Type())
    rp.Elem().Set(rv)
    return rp.Interface()
}
```

The problem with this is that you have to use type assertion on the result:

```
value := X{
    M1: ptr(time.Now().Unix()).(*int64),
    M2: ptr("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000").(*string),
    M3: ptr(slice).(*[]string),
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RAlONGo9Ku4).

#### Go 1.18 generic solution

If Go 1.18 will be allowed for you, a single helper is enough that uses no reflection:

```
func Ptr[T any](t T) *T {
    return &t
}
```

And no type assertion is needed to use it:

```
value := X{
    M1: Ptr(time.Now().Unix()),
    M2: Ptr("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"),
    M3: Ptr(slice),
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/55BF6OtvRnX).

See related: [How do I do a literal *int64 in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go/30716481#30716481)